# Programmatically add binding on IIS 8 with SNI option

Tags: .net, iis, iis-8, sni, servermanager

I'm trying to create bindings for IIS 8 that have the flag SNI checked (Server Name Indication) using Microsoft.Web.Administration library (.NET Framework).

This is necessary to me because I want to get multiple SSL bindings for the same website under IIS, all using just one IP address. This is one of the main new features of IIS 8.

I've been looking into the Binding class and I can't find any flag or option to indicate it.

Is it possible with current Microsoft.Web.Administration v 7.0.0.0? 
Will I need a new version that I haven't found?

I know that version 7.9.0.0 is only for IIS express, and it isn't my scenario, so I haven't looked into it.

Comment: More technical details behind the scene can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/05/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know/ No matter whichever source you use to acquire the MWA assembly at the very beginning, you should stick to the copy shipped with IIS (like you discovered at last).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed to do it using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` from the folder `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\` but **only in Windows 8/Windows 2012** with **IIS 8**.

These libraries had the `SslFlags` option in the `Add` function for `BindingCollection` class. There is no documentation from microsoft yet for this new overload, or at least I haven't found it.

The `SslFlags.Sni` is available to use in this one and creates the binding with SNI check perfectly.

Comment: There is a NuGet package (community one) for this now: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IIS.Microsoft.Web.Adminstration/. Don't know why MS is not updating it.

Comment: @Mrchief, Don't ever use a NuGet package. Your application should always refer to the version installed on the machine under system32\inetsrv and never copy it locally.

Comment: @LexLi Unfortunately that _practice_ is slowly getting outdated. NuGet packages and local copy (bin deployables) is the way forward!

Comment: @Mrchief, "the way forward" just does not apply to MWA, which was designed in such an OS dependent way (bind to COM unfortunately). The MWA case is not "out-of-date", but by design, and so far I don't see any change coming in this assembly.

Comment: The way forward argument was for bin deployable vs machine deployable. The official Nuget package was meant for IIS 7.x administration whereas we have IIS 10 coming now. It is by any means quite getting quite outdated.

Comment: When IIS 10 comes, you should use its own version of MWA. I can only hope that "bin deployable" breaks worse in IIS 10's case to remind people of the simple facts they neglect.

Comment: Is there a way to do this through appcmd? I have tried but it does not recoginze the sslFlags property or it could be that I'm not doing it right. The docs show the property but none of the examples show how to use it. [IIS Docs](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible with current Microsoft.Web.Administration v 7.0.0.0?

Indeed it is, by manually adding the `SslFlags` attribute to the `<binding>` node:

```
Binding mySslBinding;
bool enableSni;

using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    // ... create or get value of mySslBinding...

    mySslBinding.SetAttributeValue("sslFlags", Convert.ToInt32(enableSni ? 1 : 0));

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

See the documentation of `SslFlags` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding

Note that executing the above code on a machine with any version of IIS earlier than 8.0 will cause the `CommitChanges()` method to throw an exception, because `sslFlags` doesn't exist in those versions.

**Warning: Enabling SNI on an existing binding may cause its certificate to be unselected!**

See also [Setting Server Name Indication (SNI) takes off certificate binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536005/setting-server-name-indication-sni-takes-off-certificate-binding)

To avoid this problem, you can do this:

```
var cert = mySslBinding.CertificateHash;
mySslBinding.SetAttributeValue("SslFlags", Convert.ToInt32(1));
mySslBinding.CertificateHash = cert;
```

Comment: Doing it this way _may_ cause further issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536005/setting-server-name-indication-sni-takes-off-certificate-binding