# SNI Certificate Support With C#

Tags: c#, ssl, sni

I want to support SNI with SSL certificates(windows10 + IIS:10.0.17) using C#. Binding can be added via:

```
website.Bindings.Add(szBinding, hashBytes, sslStore);
```

How do I apply SNI on the new added Binding? The following code has no effect :

```
website.Bindings[0].SslFlags = SslFlags.Sni;
```

The question [Programmatically add binding on IIS 8 with SNI option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20469212/4284627) addresses the issue, but problem is as I described it earlier, using this flag "SslFlags.Sni" makes no effect i.e. when I check the binding in IIS, SNI Checkbox is still unchecked. Means, setting this flag does not effect on binding in IIS. I am on windows 10 with IIS v.10.0.17.

What am I missing? Any good article/help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The other question addresses the issue, but problem is as I described it earlier, using this flag "SslFlags.Sni" makes no effect i.e. when I check the binding in IIS, SNI Checkbox is still unchecked. Means, setting this flag does not effect on binding in IIS. I am on windows 10 with IIS v.10.0.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the binding value. I was using `ip:port:` instead of `ip:port:hostname`. Using Binding name with hostname and SNI flag resolved the issue.

This code will add a binding with SNI Enabled:

```
var szBinding = "IP:PORT:HOSTNAME";
website.Bindings.Add(szBinding, hashBytes, install.SslStore, SslFlags.Sni);
```